# How to mix the useful auto generated ticks() whilst also specifying the lowest granulatrity you want the tick interval to go down to

Tags: d3.js

I'm creating a time series graph using D3 and I want the x-axis ticks to go down *no lower than 2 hours* without creating too many ticks.

Take this example which builds my point:

```
 var x = d3.scaleTime().domain([new Date(2020, 4, 8).setHours(8), new Date(2020, 4, 9)])
        .range([0, 960]).ticks()
```

The ticks() automatically calculates the ticks as no count or time interval argument is given, with this result:

console.log(x) output:

```
0: Fri May 08 2020 08:00:00 
1: Fri May 08 2020 09:00:00 
2: Fri May 08 2020 10:00:00 
3: Fri May 08 2020 11:00:00 
4: Fri May 08 2020 12:00:00 
5: Fri May 08 2020 13:00:00 
6: Fri May 08 2020 14:00:00 
7: Fri May 08 2020 15:00:00 
8: Fri May 08 2020 16:00:00 
9: Fri May 08 2020 17:00:00 
10: Fri May 08 2020 18:00:00 
11: Fri May 08 2020 19:00:00 
12: Fri May 08 2020 20:00:00 
13: Fri May 08 2020 21:00:00 
14: Fri May 08 2020 22:00:00 
15: Fri May 08 2020 23:00:00 
16: Sat May 09 2020 00:00:00
```

The granularity of the time is too low here (1 hour). I know I can fix this by changing my code to:

```
 var x = d3.scaleTime().domain([new Date(2020, 4, 8).setHours(8), new Date(2020, 4, 9)])
        .range([0, 960]).ticks(d3.timeHour.every(2))
```

Which outputs:

```
0: Fri May 08 2020 08:00:00 
1: Fri May 08 2020 10:00:00 
2: Fri May 08 2020 12:00:00 
3: Fri May 08 2020 14:00:00
4: Fri May 08 2020 16:00:00 
5: Fri May 08 2020 18:00:00 
6: Fri May 08 2020 20:00:00 
7: Fri May 08 2020 22:00:00 
8: Sat May 09 2020 00:00:00
```

Perfect. However the problem is if I always pass d3.timeHour.every(2) into the ticks function it gives me way too many ticks for *every scenario*. For example if the domain is two dates which are say **5 days apart, I will get 100 ticks**, whereas if I just did ticks() for that example I would get a sensible amount of ticks.

Is there a way to tell d3 to use the auto generated ticks() for every case but at the same time don't go down to a lower time interval than 2 hours?